# What 's problem of the output in multiple process in c?

Tags: c, process, output, fork

I have the code below:

```c
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int t = fork();
        if (t == 0) {
            printf("child %d id: %ld from pid: %ld\n", i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (t > 0) {
            wait(NULL);
            printf("father %d id: %ld from pid: %ld\n", i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

When I run the output is:
[image: output1]

And when I delete the "\n" in the printf when t>0, the output is:
[image: output2]

How does the second output print more than the first one? Please!!

Sorry, I realized that this is problem about buffer in C and I just come accross this in my multithread assignment while I'm newbie in C and don't know about this yet. I just think it comes from multithread's problem so I ask here.

Comment: Please indent your code properly before posting

Comment: Terminals can do some magic with line buffering. This demonstrates well why you should always output whole lines in multi-threaded or multi-process applications that write to the same terminal.

Comment: `s/father/parent/g`.  Processes are not gendered.

Comment: `printf` does not flush the output buffer by default.  If the buffer is not flushed before a fork, then whatever is in the buffer will be written by both the parent and the child.   If `stdout` is line buffered, then including the newline in the string causes a flush.  When you remove the newline, the buffer is not flushed so you have data that is written by multiple processes.

Comment: Please copy text as such, don't post screenshots. You can copy from the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remember that `printf` does not necessarily cause any data to be written.  Instead, `printf` just writes data into an internal buffer that is flushed as needed.

Let's simplify the code a bit and unroll the loop to examine what's happening

```
int
main(void)
{
        int t, i = 0;
        t = fork();
        if( t == 0 ) {
                printf("child %d id: %ld from pid: %ld\n",
                        i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());
                exit(0);
        } else if( t > 0 ) {
                wait(NULL);
                printf("parent %d id: %ld from pid: %ld",
                        i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());
        }
        /* The output buffer now contains "parent N id ..."
           but the parent has not yet written any data.  */
        i += 1;
        t = fork();
        if( t == 0 ) {
                /* Here, the output buffer still contains "parent N id ..." */
                printf("child %d id: %ld from pid: %ld\n",
                        i, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid());
                /* The newline above causes the buffer to be flushed, 
so now this child writes "parent N id ...child M id: ..." */
                exit(0);
      ...
```

If you include the `\n` in the parent's printf, that causes (in some situations) the output buffer to be flushed so that it is empty when you call `fork` and the child does not write the additional data.  Notice that if you redirect the output to a file, you may get different behavior since the `\n` may not cause a flush in that scenario.  If you want to ensure that the buffers are flushed at any given point, call `fflush`.